# How retain (overridden) default values with pgfkeys?

Tags: pgfkeys

I'm creating a package for drawing sequence charts and make use of pgfkeys to keep default values for various parameters that I need. However, sometimes I wish to provide to my macros one or more pgfkeys key-value pairs that override the defaults stored in pgfkeys. The code below demonstrates a problem I'm having; it is stripped down to the bare minimum. There are many more keys in my original.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcount\x

\pgfkeys{/std/msg/width/.code=\def\msgwidth{#1}}
\pgfkeys{/std/msg/default/.style={
    /std/msg/width=0.7,
}}
\pgfkeys{/std/msg/default} % Set the defaults

\newcommand{\msgx}[3][]{
    \pgfkeys{/std/msg/.cd,#1} % Use provided optional params (or default)
    \draw[->] (\x,#2) -- (\x+\msgwidth,#3);
    \advance\x by 1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\msgx{1}{2} \msgx{2}{1}
\msgx[width=0.3]{1}{3}
\msgx{1}{2} \msgx{2}{1}  % Uses width=0.3 (not the default)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem with the example is that after setting width=0.3, it remains 0.3. I do want to be able to set it to something other than the default using an initialization macro (not shown), but I want the default/initialized values to be retained after the end of \msgx[width=0.3].

My questions is: What pgfkeys mechanism should I use to avoid that my optional params (#1) override the defaults?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The standard mechanism of `pgfkeys` is to rely on TeX grouping constructs, i.e. to add `\begingroup ... \endgroup` in your macro. In that case, `\endgroup`  retains all macro values (including keys) which were present in `\begingroup`

Answer (score 5):

You can keep the value changes local by introducing a group using `{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcount\x

\pgfkeys{/std/msg/width/.code=\def\msgwidth{#1}}
\pgfkeys{/std/msg/default/.style={
    /std/msg/width=0.7,
}}
\pgfkeys{/std/msg/default} % Set the defaults

\newcommand{\msgx}[3][]{
    {
            \pgfkeys{/std/msg/.cd,#1} % Use provided optional params (or default)
            \draw[->] (\x,#2) -- (\x+\msgwidth,#3);
    }
    \advance\x by 1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\msgx{1}{2}
\msgx{2}{1}
\msgx[width=0.3]{1}{3}
\msgx{1}{2}
\msgx{2}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```